# How to jump time with Sinon fake timers? (like when switching tabs then coming back later)

Tags: sinon

Based on Sinon's `fake-timers` (previously called "lolex") documentation, I don't see an API to jump forward by an amount of time for animation frames, similar to what happens when we switch to another browser tab then come back later.

How do we do it?

For example, when we switch tabs, requestAnimationFrame loops do not keep running. When we switch back, requestAnimationFrame will run again, but the first frame after switching back will see a time that has advanced forward (jumped) by a big amount compared to when running normally.

Sinon's `clock.tick` or `clock.tickAsync` will behave like when a tab is constantly focused, and it will run `requestAnimationFrame` every 16.666 (fake) milliseconds.

How do we skip (jump), say, 1 minute, without running frames, so that the behavior is like we switched tabs and came back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Sinon Fake Timers can do this. Here's a custom solution:

```js
function customFakeTimers() {
    let time = Date.now();

    const OriginalDate = globalThis.Date;
    const originalRAF = globalThis.requestAnimationFrame;
    const originalCancelRAF = globalThis.cancelAnimationFrame;

    globalThis.Date = class Date {
        static now() { return time; }

        // Good enough for my cases.
        getUTCHours() { return 0; }
        getUTCMinutes() { return 1; }
        getUTCSeconds() { return 5; }
    };

    /** @type {Map<number, FrameRequestCallback>} */
    const frameFns = new Map;
    let frameId = 0;

    /**
     * @param deltaTime - Emulate 60fps by default (16.666ms per frame).
     * Provide a custom value to make rAF skip a particular amount of time,
     * for example to emulate a tab switch and returning to a tab in which
     * case a lot more time than normal would pass since the last frame.
     */
    async function toNextFrame(deltaTime = 16.6666) {
        const currentFrames = new Set(frameFns.values());
        frameFns.clear();
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 0));
        time += deltaTime;
        for (const fn of currentFrames) { fn(time); }
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 0));
    }

    /** @param {FrameRequestCallback} fn */
    globalThis.requestAnimationFrame = (fn) => {
        frameId++;
        frameFns.set(frameId, fn);
        return frameId;
    };

    /** @param {number} id */
    globalThis.cancelAnimationFrame = (id) => frameFns.delete(id);

    return {
        toNextFrame,

        undoCustomFakeTimers() {
            globalThis.Date = OriginalDate;
            globalThis.requestAnimationFrame = originalRAF;
            globalThis.cancelAnimationFrame = originalCancelRAF;
        },
    };
}
```

To use it,

```js
const {toNextFrame, undoCustomFakeTimers} = customFakeTimers()

// ...
await toNextFrame(5000) // jump 5 seconds, as if we switched tabs and came back 5 seconds later

// ... when done,
undoCustomFakeTimers()
```